# Song that plays in Boku no Hero Academia season 4 episode 12 at 12:40

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

Does anyone know the music that starts playing in *Boku no Hero Academia* season 4 episode 12 from 12:40? I can't remember what was it called. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is it! Please forgive me if I am wrong, good day!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eh1qpioSEEk